# How to configure MULE SSH connector to authenticate against PAM

Tags: ssh, mule, mule-component

I have PAM configured PAM for SSH server on my linux.

While authenticating it prompts for two things:

```
Password:    
Verification Code:
```

I am currently using username and password based authentication on Mule side. How can I change it to incorporate **Verification Code** also.

Following is the code for my Mule-SSH connector:

```
 <ssh:connector name="%Endpoint%.connector" host="%Host%" kexTimeout="%Timeout%" port="%Port%" loginId="%Login%"
                   password="%Password%">
        <dispatcher-threading-profile doThreading="false"/>
 </ssh:connector>
```

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see in the authentication code in the connector, [you can't](https://github.com/mulesoft/sshmultiplexed-connector/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mule/modules/ssh/multiplexer/SshConnector.java#L176). The library behind the connector is sshj, if you find a way to do so feel free to raise a ticket or send a pull request.